# Getting Visual Studio Code Figure in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I was trying Visual Studio Code that comes with Anaconda

There was heaps of problems that I could not get a simple python code to run successfully there

but on the other hand there was some really nice features
beside the autocomplete feature that I liked

Using the standard plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])
```

there was the Figure which gives you many options to do with the graph including zoom in, change access and many more.

[image]

is there something similar or any other way that can give me same Figure feature in VSCode?

Comment: So how did you get this nice Figure? I've never touched VSCode in any form, but I keep getting figures of similar properties from `matplotlib`.

Comment: I got it using import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['Col1'], df['Col2']) but when I apply same code in Anaconda I just get an image of the graph, no interaction.

Comment: So you want to code python with anaconda an visual studio code? That code is executed in Anaconda command prompt, as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you select an Anaconda environment and then if you use the [Jupyter support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) you can get the plots shown in the interactive window.

Comment: how can i select Anaconda environment??

Comment: @asmgx make sure to create an Anaconda environment w/ a specified Python version and then you can [follow the docs for selecting an interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter).